# Controlling LM2596 digitally

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-divider, switching-regulator

Below schematic is how I'm going to control the output of LM2596:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMe3IH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want the output of the LM2596 to be 3-15V and it does exactly that, the problem is it's doing it inverted! When the applied voltage to the feedback pin is 0V output is 15V and when it's 12V the output is 3V.

I know that I can use an inverting opamp to simply invert the voltage before giving it to the feedback pin but then I'll need a 6V reference voltage and it's get complicated...

How can I configure the feedback pin so that 0V on feedback pin give me 3V at the output?

Comment: wait, going by your title, you've got a digital circuit generating these 0-12 V. Why not just program that to do the inverse? seems by far the most logical solution.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's a pre-regulator, DAC voltage is actually going to linear regulator and then also to the switching regulator. so that can't be done...

Comment: then, add a second DAC?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I already have 3 DACs and they just have two I2C addresses, adding another DAC will just makes everything complicated.

Comment: use a different type of DAC; or simply use some microcontroller PWM pin with a very relaxed RC filter.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If I couldn't get any help here I think I'm gonna stick with an inverting opamp, Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Wait, I thought you didn't *want* to do the inverting opamp?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Only **if** I don't get any other solution simpler than using an opamp...

Comment: OK, so what's *hard* about simply using a different type of DAC than you're using now?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm short on Arduino pins, either have to switch to mega or use a shift register IC (more complication). right now using 3 pins just to set DACs I2C addresses and I can't use another type of DAC, I only have access to MCP4725.

Comment: yeah, ok, when asking for a simple solution, people will tell you what components to use – if you can't, then you should mention that in the question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks again.

Comment: you should really go and add all the info you've given us in the comments to your question: Your load is definitely not a resistor, but a (tracking?) voltage regulator that follows your DAC output, and so on. Your question can't be answered like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you showing the [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) "simple switcher" as a 3-terminal regulator? That's extremely misleading.

In the real circuit, the regulator tries to keep its feedback pin at a constant voltage (1.235 V) with respect to ground. If you feed in more voltage from your DAC, then obviously, the regulator's output voltage must be reduced in order to meet that goal.

There's no easy way to make this type of regulator track a control voltage directly. You would need to be able to adjust the reference voltage, and that's hidden inside the chip.

Comment: Sorry about that, Circuitlab didn't have LM2596 part so...

Comment: ... so you use the "Custom Part" feature to create one.

Comment: … Circuitlab didn't have LM2596, so you can go ahead and use the "generic block" type thing to draw the actual component instead.

Comment: ... and double-click it to edit its properties including adding and deleting pins and editing the pin names.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys.